# VeeValidate does not update if input/textbox set with jQuery

Tags: vee-validate

Go here (Chrome seems to work best for this example):
https://jsfiddle.net/gongzza/m67d8f4x/2/

Type `a@b.com` into the input.  Notice how the error goes away. Now clear the input.

In the console, programmatically set the value of the email with:

`$('[name=email]').value = 'a@b.com'`

Notice how the input changes but the validation does not get refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you should use Vue to manipulate the values of these things.  The only reason I can imagine you're trying to use jQuery here is because you're doing it from outside the Vue app.  Given that, you would be better served to do this:

```
$('#app').__vue__.email = 'a@b.com'
```

That way Vue will notice the change and do it's own event handling.  I'm not sure there's a more "official" way to access the Vue data, but this is the way I've done it before.